# iOS App Persistent Settings After App Deleted

Tags: objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, settings, icloud

We are creating an app as follows:

- User starts with 2 free "tokens"
- User can buy a pack of 10 tokens with $.99 in-app purchase

We have implemented this using `NSUserDefaults` to save the number of tokens.

Is there a way to make our free 2 token setting persistent?  Even if they delete the app?  Right now you can delete the app and reinstall to get 2 tokens again.  iOS 5 has `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` for saving settings to iCloud, is that any better?

If not we will have to use a web service for this...

NOTE: This app is in MonoTouch, but probably irrelevant to the question.  Also, in our app, the user wouldn't care to reinstall the app to get 2 more tokens (there is no other settings or game progress they would lose).

Comment: any updates in 2019?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just my 2c as @Almo covers most of this already and should get the credits :-)

`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` has the *advantage* of being by-user, e.g. several devices would share the same free tokens. OTOH that might not be something you want in your app...

Leaving data after uninstallation goes against the *sandboxing* of applications. There are ways to do it, like you can add images/photos/contacts/..., but unlikely to be "Apple approved" and more than likely easy to hack around.

So I also suggest you to use a web service. A simple way would be to validate with the service (e.g. using the device's MAC address since the device unique identifier is going away) when no application data is found (install and re-install) if it's a know device (no token) or not (get tokens).

If the paid tokens are re-usable (could be re-played by re-installing a backup that includes them as data) then you might want to track them with the web service. Non-reusable tokens won't suffer from this (and are likely easier to deal with).

Comment: I think we'll go with a web service if we find our app starts to be abused.  I would rather not invest the time if the app isn't going to get much revenue in the first place.  Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 6):

You can set token to the Keychain. If the user uninstall app and install it again you can restore token from the Keychain.

[sskeychain](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you try to make the setting persistent, I don't think it would be that hard for them to find that and delete it as well during a reinstall. If you want to prevent just casual cheating, maybe that's fine. But if this is your revenue stream, I'd recommend using a webservice.

Edited to add: I don't have any experience with iCloud. That might make sense, too.

Comment: Is there an "Apple-approved" way to save settings somewhere outside your app folder?  The app folder is what gets deleted when you reinstall.  I am not worried about what a jailbroken device could do to cheat.

Comment: I don't think so. Even if there were, when you do a backup of an iPod, you can probably see those files in the backup folder and remove them, then do a restore to the backup. I have some experience with messing with this sort of thing, but I'm not a a super expert on it. If you really want to store stuff on the device, I recommend doing a thorough test to see how easy it is to remove the data.

Comment: I think we are just going to allow 1 free token for now.  I will mark you as answer if there is not a way to do it.

Comment: Good luck with that. This sort of issue is always annoying.