# Can we restrict a Free app from being downloaded or installed for a 2nd time on an iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, ios-simulator

I have to restrict a Free app from being downloaded or installed for a 2nd time on an iOS device, as I would like to user to purchase the paid version of the same. A first time user of the free App can download the Free App and install it on their iOS device, but after using the Free App for certain number of times, the Free App will work with limited functionality as I would like to promote my paid version, so I prompt the user to buy my Paid version of the App. At this time the user can delete my Free App and Re-Install the same from either the iTunes store or the iTunes on their computer or iCloud backup.
Question is how can I restrict the user from re-installing the same Free App on their iOS device a 2nd time ? 
Is there any way to tell the iOS on the user's device to stop the 2nd time install of the same Free app ?
Or is there any other way to achieve the same results ?

Thank you.

Comment: This other question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004592/ios-app-persistent-settings-after-app-deleted

Comment: This is a violation of Apples App store policy and it will NOT get through the review process. Offer a limited set of functionality in the free version and use In App purchase to allow them to unlock additional features for a fee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're unlikely to reliably get past Apple's review process with these restrictions.

Free/lite apps are supposed to be fully usable apps in their own right. So, using a todo app as an example:

- You *could* limit it to ten TODO items
- But you'd get into trouble if it stopped working after ten days

Clearly you can also limit in terms of what functionality you offer. My apps, for example, only allow editing in the paid version; the free one is read-only.

I'm not sure that you can reliably do what you want. (What about if I have to wipe my phone and restore from a backup? Does that count as reinstallation?) But even if you could, it wouldn't necessarily be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

i think the recommended way is to use in-app purchase. You can enable a full Version to the user when he buys it. So there is no reinstall needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have the requirements you do, but this does not fit the model of the App Store. You are likely to have your application rejected, even if you were to find a way to do this.

If you (or your stakeholder) are insistent in this approach, maybe the App Store is not for you.

Comment: I totally agree here, there is no full-proof way of doing this. The normal accepte way is to just give the app limited functionality and unlock these functionality if the user buy them via an IAP.